# MediaWiki: PHP Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

This relates to MediaWiki latest stable version 1.24.1

Recently noticed the following on our server logs:

MediaWiki: PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /wiki/includes/db/DatabaseMysqli.php on line 292

Before starting to debug it ourselves, we were wondering if this is something known.

Comment: You made no customizations/extensions? Also I assume this isn't actually preventing proper operation?

Comment: Every website has some customizations. I don't see any other error coming out in the logs so I assume it's working well otherwise.

Comment: Ok if you have some customizations then that where to look first. The issue is obviously something making it through to the data layer that is an object when a string is expected. So its more likely that its something in your customizations than the codebase. But as @MichalVrchota says you can check the bugreports.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should rather check/report this bug on wikimedia bugreport first.
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/